# How to align images left or right using semantically named classes?

Tags: html

I want to align images in a text. Some pictures should be on the right side and some other on the left side. I can achieve this by adding `class="right"` or `class="left"` to the `img` element. But these classnames are presentational, not semantic.

Any ideas how to align images using semantically named classes?

Comment: What do you mean by sematically correct?

Comment: @JVerstry For example, if I want to switch left and right: 
The images on the right side should be on the left side and vice versa.

Comment: Did you try to achieve this with CSS? Or do you need an example?

Comment: I know how to achieve it with CSS. But I want to use semantic class names for it. Like `even` and `odd` or so.

Comment: There is no meaning to be expressed, hence no markup can be semantic, or even structural, when you have not said what the meaning of aligning left or right is. If left or right alignment is all that is said, then the only meaning is the visual placement. If you somehow classify the images by their meaning or role, then you can ask how to make it so that some classes are aligned left, some right. But then it is a different question (and probably has rather straightforward, even trivial answer).

Comment: @ynnckhmls: CSS is inherently "unsemantic." So to say whether something is "semantically correct" or not in CSS is a moot point. Rather, I believe what you are trying to ask is how you should *name your classes* such that they have semantic, not presentational, importance. I've edited your question to reflect these changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you suggest in comments, the problem with using `left` and `right` as class names is when/if you later change the CSS to reposition these elements which then makes these class names confusing.

Ideally class names should describe the type of element, not its *position*. eg. `main-image`, `side-image`, etc.

However, if the purpose of these classes is to simply position images left/right then it can be tricky to find better names that still have some logical meaning and can be easily understood when reading the HTML source. You could use something like `side-a`, `side-b` perhaps? They don't have any real meaning, but they look they could be related and at the same time are different.

Comment: or using no class name like so, `article img {float:left;}` or `div:first-child img {float:left;}`, I rarely ever assign a class to a img.

Comment: Thanks. I’m going to use `a` and `b` only. In the CSS I only need to write: `img.a { float: left; }` and `img.b { float: right; }`.

Answer (score 1):

### Using CSS pseudo classes

I’m going to use the following CSS pseudo classes to align the images:

- `:nth-child(a)`

  - for `a` = 1 ⇒ `:first-child`
- `:nth-last-child(a)`

  - for `a` = 1 ⇒ `:last-child`
- `:nth-of-type(a)`

  - for `a` = 1 ⇒ `:first-of-type`
- `:nth-last-of-type(a)`

  - for `a` = 1 ⇒ `:last-of-type`

So I can select the `a`th image (of images). This approach completely separates markup and style.

---

#### Example

HTML:

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.</p>
<p>Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus.</p>
<img src="/path/to/image-1.ext" alt="Example #1">
<p>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</p>
<img src="/path/to/image-2.ext" alt="Example #2">
```

CSS:

```css
img:nth-child(3) {
    float: right;
}

img:nth-child(5) {
    float: left;
}

/* OR */

img:nth-of-type(1) {
    float: right;
}

img:nth-of-type(2) {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since HTML5, `align` is not an attribute to the `img` tag.   As such, aligning an image is a CSS issue and not a semantic HTML one.

As a rule, semantic HTML is to explain *what* the content is - ie is it an image, a citation, an address etc, whereas CSS styles are more for the aesthetics - is it blue, a large font, etc.  Image alignment falls under the latter category.

Giving your classes a good semantic name helps with development (allowing you to recognise your own classes in your style sheet), though there are no real standards to them (unless asked for by a third party, such as Google or Facebook, so that their robots can read them).

"Left" and "Right" are fine if you, as a developer, are sure they will always be left and right images.  For example, for use in a wysiwyg editor where you would manually want to change the alignment and adding classes is used as the way of doing so.

Comment: What are you trying to *say* with the images being aligned left and right? Not using a class at all would seem the most semantic if it is purely aesthetics.  http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/goodclassnames

Comment: ie "mainImage" would be a more semantic class name than "left", if the image's purpose was to be the main image. However, if the only quality of that image is that it aligns to the left (which is all the information your question gives), then "left" is fine.

Comment: OK, so there is actually no real semantic way.

Comment: If it says nothing, then there are no semantics to describe.  Ultimately, there is no benefit to a semantic class (unless defined by a robot to read them) other than to the individual developer, eg calling it "left" will be confusing if you want to change it to "right" down the line.  Use a name that makes it clear *to you*. This is a good article on the subject: http://www.brettjankord.com/2013/02/09/thoughts-on-semantic-html-class-names-and-maintainability/

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, for this kind of situation it doesn't really matter that the class names are technically insemantic. We use insemantic class names for lots of things like grid systems.

If you think about it, the decision of whether you align left or right is *dependent on the content* itself. The content and its presentation are tightly coupled: if the content changes, the alignment may need to change too.

From a practical perspective, at the point the alignment needs to change, you are already editing the content (HTML), so it's not a problem to change the class name.

Comment: In my opinion adding classes like `row` and `column-3` or so is like using tables. OK, the `div`s have not a semantically meaning, but it’s still like using tables.
The last argument is a good one, that the images are already the content.

Comment: @ynnc Problem is, there is no way around the grid issue. You can have main/sidebar classes sometimes, but most of the time there is no semantic class you can use, unless you want to use a unique class on every single block of content.

Comment: There is a way: don’t use a grid system, because we don’t need them. And you don’t have to add every time a class to an element. You also can use element selectors.

Answer (score -2):

for that you just have to add this code

```
style:"float:left;margin-right:10px;margin-bottom:10px;"
```

and it works fine

Comment: First off, I think you meant `style=`, not `style:`. Second, using inline styles is a bad idea, especially if this pattern is repeated many times throughout a page or site.